# Android: circle profile picture

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

I'm trying to make a profile page for my application. Here is the sample I want to create.

[image: one]

I want to know how to align circled image at the bottom of cover. I'm confused.

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could easilly add this library in your `build.gradle` :

`compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'`.

**Usage**

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/profile_image"
android:layout_width="96dp"
android:layout_height="96dp"
android:src="@drawable/profile"
app:civ_border_width="2dp"
app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

Comment: Simple and easy! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a class for a circular `ImageView` without the need for pulling in a library.

```
public class CircularImageView extends ImageView
{

public CircularImageView( Context context )
{
    super( context );
}

public CircularImageView( Context context, AttributeSet attrs )
{
    super( context, attrs );
}

public CircularImageView( Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle )
{
    super( context, attrs, defStyle );
}

@Override
protected void onDraw( @NonNull Canvas canvas )
{

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable( );

    if ( drawable == null )
    {
        return;
    }

    if ( getWidth( ) == 0 || getHeight( ) == 0 )
    {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap b = ( ( BitmapDrawable ) drawable ).getBitmap( );
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy( Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true );

    int w = getWidth( )/*, h = getHeight( )*/;

    Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap( bitmap, w );
    canvas.drawBitmap( roundBitmap, 0, 0, null );

}

private static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap( @NonNull Bitmap bmp, int radius )
{
    Bitmap bitmap;

    if ( bmp.getWidth( ) != radius || bmp.getHeight( ) != radius )
    {
        float smallest = Math.min( bmp.getWidth( ), bmp.getHeight( ) );
        float factor = smallest / radius;
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( bmp, ( int ) ( bmp.getWidth( ) / factor ), ( int ) ( bmp.getHeight( ) / factor ), false );
    }
    else
    {
        bitmap = bmp;
    }

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap( radius, radius,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas( output );

    final Paint paint = new Paint( );
    final Rect rect = new Rect( 0, 0, radius, radius );

    paint.setAntiAlias( true );
    paint.setFilterBitmap( true );
    paint.setDither( true );
    canvas.drawARGB( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    paint.setColor( Color.parseColor( "#BAB399" ) );
    canvas.drawCircle( radius / 2 + 0.7f,
            radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 + 0.1f, paint );
    paint.setXfermode( new PorterDuffXfermode( PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN ) );
    canvas.drawBitmap( bitmap, rect, rect, paint );

    return output;
}

}
```

Example use:

```
<your.package.name.CircularImageView
                    android:id="@+id/circleImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Comment: Will it work when giving image as `background` rather than `src` ??

Comment: certainly, like so `android:background="@drawable/profile_picture"`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for circle image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#1B5E20" />
        <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
        <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
    </shape>
```

and set to the image background.

```
<ImageView
                 android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:id="@+id/btnMore"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/more_apps" />
```

You can change other factor by your requirement.
Basically its use for set border to image or any layout. But its work, all you have to do is set radius by your choice, and it will circle your image.You can remove border if you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
super(context);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

if (drawable == null) {
    return;
}

if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
    return; 
}
Bitmap b =  ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() ;
Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);

int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();
Bitmap roundBitmap =  getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0,0, null);

}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
Bitmap sbmp;
if(bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
    sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
else
    sbmp = bmp;
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(),
        sbmp.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

final Paint paint = new Paint();
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
paint.setDither(true);
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
        sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);


        return output;
 }

 }
```

Comment: use in your layout file

Comment: if you are provided answers. .Please use proper code edit and also try to include comments if necessary.. rather than copy pasting all the code..

Comment: And also will it work when giving image as `background` rather than `src` ??

Comment: Its not me who asked the question :P :D. .I was just curious about the `rounded image view` .. Good solution by the way.. upvote from myself (Y)

Comment: seriously? this is the exact code I posted, 20 minutes before this.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily Android already supports a circle shape without having to declare the radius. Simply ensure that your ImageView is square:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ff0000"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem before.
I knew it is provided the CardView from androidx.

The code using the androidx is the following.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar"/>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Coordinator Layout you can add this lines to your CircleImageView:

```
    app:layout_anchor="@id/your_cover_id"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
```